# laravel centOS 8 "log file could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied”

Tags: laravel, selinux, centos8

Generally in ubuntu changing ownership to `www-data` and `775` permission solve this problem. But in centos 8 this seems not enough. What I did is-

1. Set SELinux in permissive mode
2. Allow to write in the laravel storage folder - chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage
3. sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory
4. chmod -R 775 storage/
5. Reboot the system

Nothing is working. What to do solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the projects root folder try:

```
    sudo chmod -R gu+w storage/
    sudo chmod -R guo+w storage/
    sudo chmod -R gu+w bootstrap/cache/
    sudo chmod -R guo+w bootstrap/cache/
```

Comment: You better add 
sudo chmod -R gu+w vendor/
sudo chmod -R guo+w vendor/
sudo chmod -R gu+w node_modules/
sudo chmod -R guo+w node_modules/
so npm install and composer install works especially if you use laravel sail

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue is with **selinux**

This worked for me

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/log/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS I just solved with this:
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage/

Credits: https://laravelquestions.com/2020/10/27/laravel-the-stream-or-file-storage-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-in-append-mode-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in-rhel8/#google_vignette